# "gem install mysql2" on Mac with MAMP 2.2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, rubygems, mamp

When trying to run a `rails server` in my current directory (which is a new rails project), it says that I need to install the `mysql2` gem. At first, I had no idea what this meant... Then, I did some poking around, and finally decided to install the gem. However, I am getting this super pesky error (seeing as I just spent 2 hours trying to investigate, and solve another error). I am on the brink of giving up, but I really want to try rails. Please help!

Currently, if I run `sudo gem install mysql2`, or even as some people told me to do online, `gem install mysql -- \ --with-mysql-config=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config` (I have MAMP), it gives me the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/vicky/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
-----
Don't know how to set rpath on your system, if MySQL libraries are not in path mysql2 may not load
-----
-----
Setting libpath to /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib
-----
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling client.c
compiling mysql2_ext.c
compiling result.c
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/mpapis/.sm/pkg/active/lib'
ld: library not found for -lmysqlclient
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered installing MySQL with homebrew (http://brew.sh/)?  MAMP stands for Mac-Apache-MySQL-PHP (the last part of this being the most important). I would suggest just installing MySQL directly on your box (homebrew takes care of all the heavy lifting) and afterwards I doubt you'll have any difficulty installing that gem.

To install homebrew --

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"
```

Run `brew doctor` follow any instructions and then afterwards to install MySQL run `brew install mysql` and follow any of the instructions it provides for setting up a user, etc...

============= UPDATE ==============

SO, what you'll want to do is use brew this way to install MySQL and then install the gem in the normal fashion - `sudo gem install mysql2` assuming this works, then you will be able to switch back to the old MySQL install through MAMP via -

```
sudo nano /etc/paths
```

then add this line to the top of the document -

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
```

restart your terminal and then run `mysql` to double check that you are using the MAMP installation of MySQL, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Yes, I've considered it, and I actually have brew installed. But, I actually switched from homebrew to MAMP for the reason that MAMP's virtual hosts were much better.

Comment: Thanks, and by the way, I use vim. ;-) Anyways, I had already added that to my PATH through the .bashrc file in my home directory (.zshrc for me... Go Oh-My-Zsh!). But that wasn't the problem. I don't really know what the problem was... But, I ran `brew doctor`, and followed their instructions. And that seemed to "clean up" my system.

Comment: @xanesis4 - so everything is up and running?