# Error Installing Mysql2 on OSX

Tags: mysql, macos, rubygems

Attempting to install a specific version Mysql2 Gem. And I get this:

```
sudo gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.20'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/var/rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20161017-56699-1dsu6v9.rb extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
-----
Using mysql_config at /usr/local/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
-----
Don't know how to set rpath on your system, if MySQL libraries are not in path mysql2 may not load
-----
-----
Setting libpath to /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.16/lib
-----
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling client.c
compiling infile.c
compiling mysql2_ext.c
compiling result.c
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

For reference I ran `brew install mysql` beforehand and it ran successfully. Also I tried uninstalling all versions of `brew`'s mysql references just in case.

Is there something im missing? I've looked around and most pages point back to making sure you run `brew install mysql` which I have.

In case I wasn't more clear with my above explanation, the failure I am getting is after successfully running `brew install mysql` the error is from trying to install the gem afterwards via `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.20'`

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["gem install mysql2" on Mac with MAMP 2.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935236/gem-install-mysql2-on-mac-with-mamp-2-2)

Comment: @msmith let us know how the above ref works out for you

Comment: That says the same thing as what I did, I installed it successfully with brew, however I cannot actually successfully install the gem IE `gem install mysql -v '0.3.20'` afterwards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for reference what ended up working was `xcode-select --install` which seemed to install the OpenSSL libraries which took care of the `ld: library not found for -lssl` issue.

Answer (score 4):

**How to make it work on MacOS Mojave.**

Make sure `openssl` is installed on Mac via Homebrew:

```
brew install openssl
```

Then install `mysql2` gem following this special way:

```
gem install mysql2 -v 'x.x.x' -- --with-ldflags=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib --with-cppflags=-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
```

where x.x.x - specified version of the mysql2 gem.

Comment: Also worked for me on Catalina.

I had the flags set up as LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib" and CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include" in my ~/.zshrc but I guess there were the wrong version or didn't do the trick anyway.